How to get cloudflare streaming video URL?
I have install and configured https://www.drupal.org/project/cloudflare_stream module in Drupal 10. I have used "Field type" as "Cloudflare Video" for upload file field.
I haven't received any response to save after complete the file upload.
Video file is locating my LOCAL path only, not cloudflare streaming video path.

I am expecting the data "Video ID" , "Video URL" and "Video streaming URL".
How to display the cloudflare streaming video ?

I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug report: https://www.drupal.org/project/cloudflare_stream/issues/3445899. This website is for questions.
